# Get specific cell of a selected DataGridViewRow in editmode independent of the cell, which is entered for selection

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, which has two columns and several rows. The first column has the names of some attributes of an object and the second one should be filled with values by the user.

How can I get the second column of a selected row automatically in editmode independent of the column, which is entered to select the row?
This means, if a row is selected it should be immediately possible to enter some values into the second column of that specific row, even if the row is selected by entering the first column of the row.

By now, the first column has the property `DataGridRowColumns.ReadOnly = true` and the second one has `DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly = false`. The grid has the following properties: `DataGridView.MultiSelect = false` and `DataGridView.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect`.

Comment: And your question is..? those properties have nothing to do with getting the value of a specific column in EditMode
Are you wanting something like this for example 
`DataGridViewRow rowSelected = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Cell value of DataGridView by column name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436553/how-to-get-cell-value-of-datagridview-by-column-name)

Comment: I don't want the value of a specific column, I want a specific cell to be in editmode. I try to change the formulation of my post and change it to a question.

Comment: you need to edit your question Title to depict that otherwise you're going to get improper answers

Comment: Feel free to make any suggestions for a more proper title to my question. For me it's quiet hard to formulate it without making it a very long title.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
protected void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
    {
            DataRowView dataItem1 = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            var result = (string)dataItem1.Row["YourColumnName"];
            ......
    }    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help.