# Deleting a row in a database from datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to remove an entry from both the datagridview and the database. I got it so it removes the row from the data grid view but it fails to delete it also from the database. Here is my code I have in place:

```
  private void listBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        MySqlDataAdapter mysqldatadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select id, username from members ORDER BY id", new MySqlConnection(conn.connectionString));

        mysqldatadapter.Fill(ds);

        dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        listBtn.Enabled = false;
  }


  private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        using (MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(conn.connectionString))
        {
            dbConn.Open();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[i];

                if (row.Selected == true)
                {
                    dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);

                    MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM members WHERE id = " + i;

                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            dbConn.Close();
        }
  }
```

I'm at a loss concerning this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Update - Is there a way to grab the value of individual cells to pass to the mysql command? For instance, grabbing the id?

Comment: Hard to tell, but likely your values for `i` don't match the ID column in the `members` table.

Comment: that's what I was thinking. Is there a way to get the cell's value?

Answer (score 0):

Your values for `i` probably don't match the `id` fields in the `member` table.

You probably need to change this line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM members WHERE id = " + i;
```

to

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM members WHERE id = " + row.cells[id.Index].ToString();
```

Comment: When I change that, I get an error saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataGridViewRow'.

Comment: @bashis thanks I think you're right. Been a while since I've used DataGridViews

Comment: @dave turns out it's a bit harder than that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436553/how-to-get-cell-value-of-datagridview-by-column-name/

Comment: @bashis argh. what a pain.

Comment: I've updated the answer according to what should work as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20474611/361762