# How to get the selected cell value of a datagridview filled with sql data?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I need to get the value of a selected cell on a datagridview when the user clicks on it.

I've tried to bring the value to a textbox to test the click event but when I click on it, the textbox doesn't show the cell value.

```
 private void btnsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Obtiene el catálogo de presupuestos

    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\MYINSTANCE;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        string cmd = "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');";

        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = true;
            txtpresup.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].FormattedValue.ToString();
        }


    }
```

I expect that the "textpresup" text box is filled with the value of the selected cell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436553/how-to-get-cell-value-of-datagridview-by-column-name/20474611#20474611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedrowindex];
                string value = selectedRow.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();

                txtpresup.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Don't forget to change `Cells[0]` to either the column index (eg `Cells[4]`) or the column name (eg `Cells["Name"]`)

However, if this code is triggered and no cell/row has been selected you're likely to get a `null reference error`

Comment: well this was useful to get it right, but I had an exception of an index out of range, thanks for the answer!